# Microservice Architecture For Blog Posts With Media Content

Tags: architecture, microservices

I was reading the guide about microservices from https://microservices.io/ (still very new to this architecture) and had a question about a design approach.

Let's say i have a blog applications with users, blog posts, etc, and the blog posts can have media attached. Now i want to have a microservice that manages all the media content (uploading, serving, deleting images, videos, audio, etc) and a microservice that manages the blog posts (creating posts, commenting, replies, saved/favorited posts, likes, etc).

If a users sends a POST request to create a blog post and attached media to it, how would i design the microservice architecture to where the blog post in the posts microservice cannot be created unless the media successfully uploaded from the media microservice? Would the posts microservice send/emit a message to the queue and wait/listen to a "successfully uploaded" event in order to continue creating the blog post? If so, Isn't that coupling? Like twitter and facebook for example, how is the backend architecture set up to handle 2 microservice to complete a single action?

Answer (score 3):

Like most of architecture questions, the answer is - it depends, and in any approach that you choose there is a trade-off.

1. First way to approach it is a synchronous approach - the posts service receives a `POST` request with an attachment, then it uploads the attachment to the media service an waits for `200` response code, afterwards - returns `200` response to indicate that the post uploaded successfully. this approach maintains ***consistency***, meaning - if you got `200` response from the posts service, you can be sure that the attachment uploaded successfully via the media service. The trade-off here is ***latency*** - obviously it will take the posts service more time to respond, since it waits for the media service to handle the request.
2. Another approach which handles the ***latency*** issue can be, as you described, an events-driven approach. You can create an attachments queue, and then when the posts service receives a request with an attachment - it sends a message to the attachments queue which is being listened by the media service. After sending the message, the posts service can return a response, and the media service will handle the new attachment message on the side. By that you solved the latency issue, since sending a message to the queue is obviously faster than waiting the media service to upload a file, however you'll need to handle a new issue - what happens if the media service experience some failure during attachment upload, after posts service already returned `200` response on the post?

To summarize, my point is - there is no a 'correct' answer for this and it's totally up to your case. You need to map an analyze the architecture characteristics which are important for you (latency, consistency, availability, testability, and more...), and decide what solution fits. Remember - ***there will be always a trade-off***.

If you'd like to learn more about this, I highly recommend the textbook [Fundamentals of Software Architecture](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/fundamentals-of-software/9781492043447/)

Comment: Thanks. in this example, i think the easiest thing is for the posts service handle its own media content so it can truly be independent of other services.

Comment: @ryanwaite28 indeed this is another legit approach which maintains deployability - changes that related to posts/media will require deployment in one component only (the posts service). Again - it's all about the characteristics that are most important for you.